# Woocommerce breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I want to change the default Woocommerce breadcrumbs on the tag archives. Currently they are "Home / Products tagged with "..." ", and I just want "Home / Tag name".

I could not find anything on how to achieve this, the Woo docs just explain how to change the delimiter or change the word "Home".

Answer (score 0):

You can see it at wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-breadcrumb.php with

private function add_crumbs_product_tag() 
{

```
    $current_term = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get_queried_object();

    $this->prepend_shop_page();

    /* translators: %s: product tag */
    $this->add_crumb( sprintf( __( 'Products tagged &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), $current_term->name ) );
}
```

just change **'Products tagged “%s”'** to **'%s'** if you permanently remove **product tagged...**. Make sure you are changing  private function of woocommerce.

Comment: You're not supposed to edit core files like that. Next time WooCommerce updates, it'll remove your edit.